# How do you describe a language that is generated by Context Free Grammer

Tags: context-free

I am familiar with describing Regular Expressions but when it comes to describing CFG I get confused. Do you describe it in words like you would regular expressions or do you do something like this ?

this is the CFG I am trying to describe

```
S -> SS 
S -> XXX 
X -> aX| Xa| b
```

I was thinking something like this

```
S-> SS
  ->XXXS
  ->aXXXs
  ->abXXS
  ->abXXS
  ->abXAXS
  ->abbaXS
  ->abbabS
  ->abbabS
  ->abbabXXX
  ->abbabbXX
  ->abbabbbX
  ->abbabbbb
  ->abbabbbb
```

Comment: That's not a description of the langauge: it's an example of a single string in the language.  A description of a language would be something like "All strings containing twice as many $a$s as $b$s" or "All strings of even length containing three $b$s".

Comment: Yes, you describe it in words. What you are thinking of is how to derive a single string in a CFG.

Comment: The CFG *is* a description! What do you mean by "description", then? Can you give an example for regular langages? (The language generated by this grammar is regular, I think.)

Comment: @Raphael I was thinking something like David did...

Comment: @DavidRicherby how did you get three b's ?

Comment: @Dana Those were just examples; they weren't intended to be descriptions of the specific language you posted.

Comment: @Raphael There is a simple description of the language in this case. In fact, it's decided by a DFA with four states, and there is also a simple English description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: How many $b$s are there in each word generated by this grammar?

Guidance: What is the language generated by $X$? What is the language generated by $XXX$? What is the language generated by $S$?

Comment: I am thinking only one ? I am confused about S and X

Comment: Well, in the example you give there are 6, so certainly there can be more than one.

Comment: @FrankW It's a hint. If followed, it does provide an answer to the question. Try to solve the question yourself and you'll find out.

Comment: I am even more confused now...I over thinking this